# realloc() not behaving as expected when shrinking char *

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I am attempting to shrink the pointer "ptr" with realloc() as show in this sample code:

```
char * ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
int i;
for(i = 0;i<7;i++){
    ptr[i]= "pointer"[i];
}
puts(ptr);
ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(char) * 3);
puts(ptr);
free(ptr);
```

Expecting the code to free the unused memory i thought that it would return the following:

```
pointer
poi
```

However, it instead returns this:

```
pointer
pointer
```

Is this an error on the compiler's part, or is this an error in my understanding of realloc()?

Comment: Given that your char * is not null terminated, I expected demons to fly out of your nose.

Comment: Note: you cannot shrinking a _pointer_, but the object it **points to**. And you are invoking undefined behaviour, as you are not terminating the string after the shrink. The first loop happens to terminate the string you copy, but you are allocation one `char` less than required: also undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: A `char *` is never NUL terminated, as it is a pointer. I presume you mean the C-string it points to.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, but this char * does not point to a C-string.

Comment: It's an error in your understanding of `puts`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I did not say different.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: More in how/that a C string has to be NUL-ternimated.

Comment: @Olaf it seems to me that he thinks `puts` reads up to  the end of the allocated memory block, when in fact it reads a C string.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand what you mean by "I did not say different".  This char * points to some memory, and the object it points to is not a null terminated string.  You are correct that I was sloppy to say the "char * is not null terminated" when I should have said "the object the char * points to is not null terminated."

Comment: @WilliamPursell Since we're being really pedantic here :) The *string* is not null terminated. (An object is a region of storage; a string may exist inside that region).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I apparently have my bad-English-hours - getting late here and I will stop right after this: You are right - my appologies! good night;-)

Comment: Normal people would write `memcpy(ptr, "pointer", 7)` instead of a loop.  Also, it would be a really good idea to allocate space for, and copy, the terminating zero-byte of the C string.  You could get all of this to happen with `strdup()`.  This isn't the source of your use-after-free bug (which the answers explain correctly), but does avoid depending on the bytes after the buffer you `malloc` to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realloc` returns an updated pointer that points to a chunk of memory of (at least) the requested size. It can do so either by allocating a new chunk of memory and deallocating the old one, *or* by returning the original pointer value (and updating the system's internal bookkeeping information to track the updated size). If it allocates a new chunk of memory, it copies data from the old location; the amount copied is the old size or the new size, whichever is smaller.

```
char * ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
int i;
for(i = 0;i<7;i++){
    ptr[i]= "pointer"[i];
}
puts(ptr);
```

This has undefined behavior.  `puts` requires a pointer to a string, and a string requires a null character `'\0'` to terminate it. So for a string with a length of 7 characters, you need to allocate 8 bytes. (And once you've done that, you can use `strcpy` to copy the data.)

It *seems* to work because there probably just happens to be a null character in the location just past the end of the allocated memory.

```
ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(char) * 3);
puts(ptr);
```

More undefined behavior. After the `realloc` call `ptr` points to (at least) 3 bytes of memory. Since the new size is smaller than the old size, the system is able to place the new chunk in the same place as the old one; it just marks it as having a smaller size.

So by "luck", `ptr` points to a sequence of characters:

```
'p', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', '\0'
```

but only the first 3 of those bytes are in memory that you can safely access.

`realloc` *could* have allocated a new chunk of memory, and the data past the end of that chunk *could* have contained something other than `'n', 't', 'e', 'r', '\0'`. For that matter, the memory past the end of the new smaller chunk could have been clobbered even if `realloc` returned a pointer to the same location.

One more thing: `realloc` returns a null pointer if it was unable to allocate memory. You should always check for that, even if you're trying to shrink the allocated memory. And if `realloc` fails, it leaves the original allocated memory alone; you should consider assigning the result to a different pointer object so you can still access the original memory. (Unless you're going to terminate the program anyway; then it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand realloc.  realloc does not necessarily move the data to a new location, and since you are shrinking the memory it almost certainly (depending on the implementation) will not.  It does not (necessarily) modify the original contents, and in your case it has not.  Your program is invoking undefined behavior, and there is no error except in the program.  (Invoking `puts` with a char * that does not point to a null terminated string is an error.)

Comment: `realloc` [**does move**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p2) the data to the new location!

Comment: @Olaf He meant it does not necessarely changes the location where it is.

Comment: @Havenard: "doen not necessarily allocate a different memory area then?  That is really hard to read from "realloc does not necessarily move the data to a new location". He really should clarify this.

Comment: @Olaf realloc *may* move the data to a new location.  In this case, it isn't necessary and didn't happen.

Comment: @Olaf the new location may have the same memory address as the old location. In that case the data would not be moved.  (Note that the C11 text does not say that the data is moved, just that the old and new objects have the same contents)

Comment: Yes, I got it now with the help of @Havenard. Sorry, as a non-native speaker I find it very easy to missinterpret. Might be language-gap, but normally i'm not that bad at understanding English text.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the pointer is not being changed when you shrinked, leaving the data in the same place.

So the remaining 5 bytes `nter\0` are still there, outside the allocated area, but in the same place right next to it. Notice strings in C are null-terminated, which means a symbol `\0` (character with value zero), is used as sentinel to determine where the string ends.

When you print a C string, it will print until it finds a `\0`, even if this `\0` is outside the scope of the allocated memory space, invoking what is generalized as "undefined behaviour", something that you should not be doing, that may or may not work, or may or may not crash, depending on the conditions.

Even if it did move your variable to some other place in memory, it would move only the `poi` part, and the null-terminator would be missing, causing you to have a malformed string, leading to more undefined behaviour. It would print memory garbage until it crashes or finds a `\0`.

Comment: Worst thing happening invoking UB is that is _seems_ to work (during testing). Acording to Murphy's law it will eventually cause maximum trouble in the most unpleasant situation. (hope that is understandable).